# Окончание слова "основание"

Tags: грамматика, окончания

Есть следующее предложение:

> Элементы покрытия соединяются только между собой: замковую
> кварц-виниловую плитку, в отличие от клеевой, не нужно фиксировать на
> основании.

Корректно ли писать здесь "на основаниИ", а не "на основаниЕ"? Или уместны оба варианта?

Answer (score 2):

Фиксировать *на чём?* — на основаниИ.